# POST data using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to get form data to node server using POST method.
This is my HTML code,

```
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>
                Node Architecture
            </title>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Node Architecture</h1>
    <h3>Enter Your name.</h3>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="eventname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my node app, index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
//var io = require('socket.io')(http);
//var qs = require('querystring');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});
app.get('/events', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('events.html');
});
app.get('/movie', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('movie.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.eventname;
    console.log(name);
});



http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Now when I click submit I get an error message which is as follows,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventname' of undefined at Object.handle
```

How do I print the entered name to my console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express doesn't parse request body by default, you will have to use a middleware to do that.

Try this.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
    .use(express.bodyParser());

...
...
```

Also, you should read this [article](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html). It explains some of the problems (and their solutions) related to common body parsing approach.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines into your app.js.

require body-parser.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

put before your first app.get that will be better.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

good luck.